# visual basic to parse cells in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm working on a visual basic script to parse a specific form of excel spreadsheet and pull various data from it. I have little experience with VB, so any help would be appreciated.

As you can see, the script moves through the spreadsheet, pulling data from various specific points. But at the end, in the Pull Journal Data out For loop, I get the following error in the Command Prompt.

```
test parse(92, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error.
```

Code that throws this error:

```
rem Pull Journal Information out alone
For x = 7 to UsedRowsCount
    For y = 0 to 5
        If y= 0 Then
            WScript.Echo vbCRLF
        End If
        dim word
        word = objExcel.Cells(x,y).value
        WScript.Echo word
    Next
Next
```

I'm flummoxed because I use very similar loops in the section before with no trouble. As in this loop above:

```
rem Report Total Aggregate Data for range covered
WScript.Echo "Total from all Journals by Month"
For i = 6 to UsedColumnsCount
    WScript.Echo Cells(5,i).value
    Wscript.Echo Cells(6,i).value
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated. I copy the whole messy script below here:

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _ 
    ("E:\Focus\Internship\Code\VB\emerald_jr1_2012.xls")


dim Sheet
set Sheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
usedColumnsCount = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
usedRowsCount = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

dim Cells
set Cells = Sheet.Cells


REM Test to see if it's a jr1
if Cells(1,1).Value = "Journal Report 1 (R3)" then
    WScript.Echo "File is a jr1 report."
else
    WScript.Echo "File is NOT a recognized report"
end if


rem Test to determine how many months are covered in the report and what year
dim lastMonth
select case usedColumnsCount
    Case 9
        lastMonth = "only"
    Case 10
        lastMonth = "through Feb"
    Case 11
        lastMonth = "through Mar"
    Case 12
        lastMonth = "through Apr"
    Case 13
        lastMonth = "through May"
    Case 14
        lastMonth = "through Jun"
    Case 15
        lastMonth = "through Jul"
    Case 16
        lastMonth = "through Aug"
    Case 17
        lastMonth = "through Sep"
    Case 18
        lastMonth = "through Oct"
    Case 19
        lastMonth = "through Nov"
    Case 20
        lastMonth = "through Dec"
    Case Else
        lastMonth = "uncertain"
end select
WScript.Echo "Report holds values for Jan " & lastMonth


rem Using VBS built-in support of Regular expressions to parse the year indicated in a particular row: the first date header.
dim dateYear
dateYear = Cells(5,6).value
rem The dates come out in the script formated as 1/1/2012
rem WScript.Echo dateYear

set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ".*?((?:(?:[1]{1}\d{1}\d{1}\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\d{3})))(?![\d])"
Set matches = re.Execute(dateYear)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    Set match = matches(0)
    If match.Submatches.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 0 to match.SubMatches.Count-1
            WScript.Echo "Report covers year " & match.Submatches(i)
        Next
        End If
Else
    WScript.Echo "Error, year data not found"
End If

rem Report Total Aggregate Data for range covered
WScript.Echo "Total from all Journals by Month"
For i = 6 to UsedColumnsCount
    WScript.Echo Cells(5,i).value
    Wscript.Echo Cells(6,i).value
Next

rem Pull Journal Information out alone
For x = 7 to UsedRowsCount
    For y = 0 to 5
        If y= 0 Then
            WScript.Echo vbCRLF
        End If
        dim word
        word = Cells(x,y).value
        WScript.Echo word
    Next
Next

objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close
objExcel.Quit

set Sheet = Nothing
set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid range for the ColumnIndex argument of Cells() starts at 1:

I think you meant to write :

```
rem Pull Journal Information out alone

For x = 7 to UsedRowsCount

    For y = 0 to 5

        If y= 0 Then

            WScript.Echo vbCRLF

        Else

            WScript.Echo objExcel.Cells(x,y).Value

        End If

    Next y

Next x
```

You don't need the *word* variable unless the very last value is used somewhere else. It's a bad idea to dim a variable inside a loop, although Excel will probably optimise this out.